# Using the vitae package in R, how do I change the appearance of my website name?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I want to create a resume for job applications, and I would like to link my website. My problem is that the name of my website domain is weird - a random pairing of words and numbers because it costs less. I would like to make the website appear as a hyperlink that says something like "Academic website." However, in the vitae package, I can't figure this out. The usual method of name_appearance doesn't work. This probably has something to do with the .cls file that vitae uses to compile the document, but I'm no good with LaTeX. Any thoughts?

When I run the code below in RMarkdown, I get an error; when I take away the brackets and parentheses following the www: it compiles, but then the website name is stackoverflow. I would like it to say "Personal website."

````
---
name: John
surname: Doe
phone: "999-999-9999"
www: [Personal website](https://stackoverflow.com/)
output: vitae::awesomecv
headcolor: 414141
docname: Resume
---

<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
library(vitae)
library(tibble)
```
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------->



<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------->
# Summary
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------->

Bleep bloop I make beepy sounds.
````